# In-Spotify Apps: What to do?

Tags: spotify

with regards to the shutting down of In-Spotify Apps (you know, the ones that show up in App Finder for premium users?) I am wondering how to migrate away?

The in-spotify apps allow for some cool use-cases (I have a number of apps, that I use, as well as some that I have developed) which will be lost now. Is there any way forward, about all I can think of is building an entire Spotify client with libspotify and/or the mobile SDKs, and include my extra functionality in there?

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what your exact use cases are, it is hard to say which alternatives exist, if any. Did you have a look at the [Spotify Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/)?

Comment: One use case is to display a photo depending on who added a song. I have done this in the past, which has been useful when sharing playlists around with friends who have never met. As an in-spotify app this is very simple to do, and can be achieved in short time with low amount of code. As a external app, then all the extra player code, the UI etc all need to be taken care of by the developer.... the barrier of entry with in-spotify apps was lower that using the SDKs

Comment: I think "the barrier of entry with in-spotify apps was lower that using the SDKs" is debatable. Not only was the Apps API a totally new set of methods to learn for a third-party developer, but it was in part not following conventions (e.g. promises). Also, to get an application published within the Desktop client could take months of back-and-forth with Spotify's QA.

Comment: Debatable? Absolutely! My first few attempts were pitiful and horrible! However once I got the basic structure it wasn't too bad - as I say, within the context and limitations, I could have an "app" up and running very quickly - also very useful for Proof-of-Concept (which sidesteps the approval process). The other benefit, obviously was that you could have many apps in one place, rather than multiple apps to do multiple things. Anyway, I think we've answered my original question, and much as I'd love to continue the conversation, perhaps SO is not the right place for it :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a question that could be answered like a programming question, so I don't expect a 'Correct Answer' for this response. ;-)

If you believe that there's enough value in maintaining a Spotify client that 
allows third-party integrations to live inside it, I think you should go for it. Libspotify and the mobile SDKs should be enough, but I can imagine that it's a lot of work to create and maintain it.

There's a Web Player-like application at http://lab.possan.se/thirtify/#/ ([Source code](https://github.com/possan/webapi-player-example)) that's only using the Web API. Since the Web API only supports 30 second previews of tracks, the application won't do playback of full tracks. Hopefully this restriction is an issue that can be solved soon.

The purpose of the Web API, Libspotify, and the mobile SDKs is that developers would work without the restrictions set by Spotify's clients. A lot of the applications that were available in the desktop client could be rebuilt using the Web API, or even better, as mobile applications. The only drawback is that they won't be discoverable through Spotify's desktop client. The Spotify Apps API also supported some functionality that isn't offered in the Web API, most importantly playback of full tracks. Regarding the discoverability, there's a [Developer Showcase](https://developer.spotify.com/showcase/) where Spotify shows off good examples of third-party integrations. Admittedly, more could be done to make smaller third-party apps discoverable.

To conclude, I don't really mind third-party applications not being available in the desktop client, but I think Spotify or its developer community could do more to improve the discoverability of these applications.

Comment: cheers mate - I have actually flirted with the possibility of forking the current player to cater for in-app-app's; i have been waiting to see what the progress is though with the SDKs and what others are doing.